# Application Insights: CorrelationIdManager error in node js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-application-insights

I am using application insights on my node js application and I keep on getting this error. Can you please help me

```
ApplicationInsights:CorrelationIdManager [ { Error: unable to verify the first certificate
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1105:38)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\src\xyz\xyz\xyz\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:275:35)
at Zone.runTask (C:\src\xyz\xyz\xyz\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:151:47)
at TLSSocket.ZoneTask.invoke (C:\src\xyz\xyz\xyz\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:345:33)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:639:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:469:38) code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' } ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing this error because of transient problems on the Application Insights backend, but the error should not be fatal and your app should continue working as expected (albeit with this message being printed).

In the default configuration of the Application Insights SDK for Node.js, communication with the backend is retried - so you should be able to ignore this error and still see telemetry show up in the Azure Portal.

If you've changed the defaults, the setting you'll want to make sure to set is `.setUseDiskRetryCaching(true)` For example:

```
appInsights.setup("key")
    .setUseDiskRetryCaching(true)
    .start()
```

If you want to suppress messages like this from the SDK you can disable internal logging: (Be aware you'll be suppressing other errors potentially as well)

```
appInsights.setup("key")
    .setUseDiskRetryCaching(true)
    .setInternalLogging(false, false)
    .start()
```

If you're curious about the history of this issue, and why it spontaneously occurs, there's a long-running issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/180

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have changed the defaults, but I am still using _setUseDiskRetryCaching(true)_ , and I am still getting this error. Can you please confirm that after having right settings and getting the error is non-fatal ?

Comment: This error is indeed non-fatal. The SDK will simply try again until it succeeds. (Of course telemetry loss is possible if retries _never_ eventually succeed). I would expect a new version to be released soon with this PR included that actually hides these errors when retries are working correctly - to make it clearer when there is a potential problem and when there isn't: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/pull/395

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciate your support. :)

Comment: Now we are seeing increased exceptions for the same error. Is there any way to solve this certificate issues. It is now complaining that it has retried max number of times. Please refer to my question at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264174/application-insights-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264174/application-insights-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-node-js)