# Application Insights : Unable to verify the first certificate in node js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-application-insights

The application insights keeps on throwing the following error every few minutes.

> ApplicationInsights:Sender [ 'Ingestion endpoint could not be reached 5 consecutive times. There may be resulting telemetry loss. Most recent error:',
>     { Error: unable to verify the first certificate
>       at TLSSocket.\u003canonymous\u003e (_tls_wrap.js:1116:38)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/usr/src/app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:275:35)
>       at Zone.runTask (/usr/src/app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:151:47)
>       at TLSSocket.ZoneTask.invoke (/usr/src/app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:345:33)
>       at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
>       at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:643:8)
>       at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:473:38) code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' } ]

I reviewed the discussion [GITHUB DISCUSSION](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/180) and tried some proposed solution but it did not work.

Here is the code that I am using to connect to application insights.

```
let appInsights = require('applicationinsights');
appInsights.setup(config.APPINSIGHTS_KEY.trim())
  .setAutoDependencyCorrelation(true)
  .setAutoCollectRequests(true)
  .setAutoCollectPerformance(true)
  .setAutoCollectExceptions(true)
  .setAutoCollectDependencies(true)
  .setAutoCollectConsole(true)
  .setUseDiskRetryCaching(true)
  .start();
```

I am not 100% sure if there is any telemetry loss or not, but getting these errors all the time is annoying. Please help.

Answer (score -2):

I've updated the github discussion thread. A fix on the ingestion side is in the works.

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/180#issuecomment-475699485

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question so that your answer is contained within the text. SO is a Q&A database and it is important that material information is here, not elsewhere where it may disappear over time (and where it cannot effectively be used by a search engine to retrieve this question). Thanks.